# How to use Pentaho Denormalizer Step with Metadata Injection

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi, data-integration

I want to denormalize the below data.
Input
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWUie.png)

Required output

```
col1   col2   col3   col4

aaa    bbb    ccc    ddd
```

I think in Pentaho we can use Metadata Injection step with Denormalizer step to dynamically denormalize all row values to columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible. One constraint is you need to provide your input data twice.
I have prepared a solution , you can see dynamic denormalize from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/181PxOT11Jw4IB7v1ilJOeHdnrQSvuE9m?usp=sharing)

Comment: Perfect! This is what I wanted.. Thanks a lot